# Pandas plot with only tow dates as index

Tags: pandas, datetime, plot

I have this simple pandas dataframe with dates as index:

`df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[20,30,12],'b':[15,18,18]},index=['2021-10-7','2021-10-8','2021-10-9']) df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)` 
when I try to plot a simple pandas.plot with **only two dates** in xaxis

```
df.iloc[-2:].plot()
```

it gives me the following plot with lot of numbers in axis

[image: Plot for only tow dates]

Plot works fine if I plot the entire db: `db.plot()`

Thank you for support

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add below line after setting your index to make it work.

```
df.index.freq = 'D'
```

So Your entire code looks like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[20,30,12],'b':[15,18,18]},index=['2021-10-7','2021-10-8','2021-10-9']) 

df.index  = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df.index.freq = 'D'
```

**Alternatively:**

You can also use date_range like below :
Please note this would work only if your data is like the one provided which has frequency of daily, You need to adjust in cases where the frequencies are different.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[20,30,12],'b':[15,18,18]},index=['2021-10-7','2021-10-8','2021-10-9']) 

df.index=pd.date_range(start = '2021-10-07', end='2021-10-09')
```

Both approaches will give you same plot which you have mentioned in the question(similar to bottom one in the provided question)